# Linq: how to get values of second level nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml that looks like

```
<response>
 <book>
   <title>Harry Potter</title>
   <Price>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Amount>$19.89</Amount>
   </Price>
</book>
</response>
```

I have no problem getting the title element, but when I'm trying to get all values within price, it doesn't work.

```
var prices = from price in xmlDoc.Descendants("Price")
             select new
             {
                  currency = price.Element("currency").Value,
                  amount = price.Element("amount").Value,
             };
```

Comment: "currency" != "Currency"

Comment: It's not a problem. I've tried lower case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your XML snippet, this code can populate a sequence of objects

```
var books = from book in document.Descendants("book")
            let title = book.Element("title").Value
            let price = book.Element("Price")
            let currency = price.Element("Currency").Value
            let amount = price.Element("Amount").Value
            select new
            {
                Title = title,
                Price = new
                {
                    Currency = currency,
                    Amount = amount
                }
            };
```

This structure follows the same hierarchy as established by the XML. You can, of course, flatten it into a single level if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the casing of the currency and amount elements to title casing and it worked fine.

```
var prices =
    from price in xmlDoc.Descendants("Price")
    select new
    {
        currency = price.Element("Currency").Value,
        amount = price.Element("Amount").Value,
    };
```

XML is case-sensitive.

Comment: How can I add xml file which project I need to take is it Linq to sql project or just take simple 'empty web' project  please explain

Comment: @ashuthinks - You just need to reference the `System.Xml.Linq` assembly & add the appropriate `using` declarations to use linq to xml.